# Elastic: How to visualize data based on the problem as discussed below?

Tags: elasticsearch, visualization, kibana, elastic-stack

The system I am using generates logs for every device, each device has a unique serial number(serial_number in logs). As the devices are active we get logs every minute so if some device is closed then we won't receive its log from the next minute till the time it is turned on again.

What I want to do is to find inactive devices. Inactive devices are considered those that were present in logs an hour ago but are not present now. So basically I have to filter the serial_number of devices that are not being logged from last minute but were getting logged an hour ago.

At first I tried creating visualization with elastic search DSL query but was unable to write the query even with aggregation pipeline so I moved on to look if one can integrate AWS lamda with visualization, that way I would process the data from logs on the lambda and pass it to the visualization to show but I couldn't find any solution this way too, then I explored Heart Beat, Logstash and such but still couldn't find any solution.

 Please comment out any possible way to visualize the count/list of inactive devices.